# Rename column name from a values function

Tags: db2

When you execute a command like the following

```
db2 "select count(IBMREQD) from sysibm.sysdummy1"
```

You can rename the name of the column like

```
db2 "select count(IBMREQD) qty from sysibm.sysdummy1"
```

I would like to know if it is possible to rename the columns of a result set returned by values, like the following:

```
db2 "values varchar(current path)"
```

To something like:

```
db2 "values varchar(current path) current_Path"
```

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: Better output when executing scripts that have different configuration (schema prod is different from schema test) and the execution log has to be self-descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only assign aliases to columns in the `SELECT` clause of a subselect, and the `VALUES` statement is in itself a sort of subselect, so you cannot modify what it does. You have to wrap `VALUES` in another `SELECT` statement, for example

```
select * from table( values varchar(current path)) as t( current_Path )
```

which is basically the same as

```
select varchar(current path) as current_Path from sysibm.sysdummy1
```